# Stop text from spanning entire scroll

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a scroll bar with multiple images, that open a new link when each image is clicked. On hover, I have it set to "gray out" and text appears.

I cannot get that text to only pop up on the single image it is designed for, and all the images text appears as soon as you hover over any part of the div.

Here is a fiddle I made to explain: https://jsfiddle.net/burgoyne/u1zdn80p/

CSS:

```
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#scroll {
    height: 25%;
    overflow-x: scroll;    
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 50%;
}

#scroll img {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top; /* this prevents vertical whitespace */
}

#scroll img:hover {
  opacity: .3;
}

#scroll .text {
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
}

#scroll:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="scroll">
    <a href="http://www.google.ca"><img src="http://www.fotoviva.co.uk/image/cache/data/prods/doug-blue-lake-500x500.jpg" class="hover"/><p class="text">Lake</p><!--
```

If anyone can figure out how to make the text only appear on a specific image, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: you set hover effect on div so that's you when you hover anywhere on div those text show. replace #scroll:hover with  a:hover .text { visibility:visible; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your fiddle you need set position relative and set height for anchor tag. and set display:table-cell. So for image you dont need that vertical-align:top to prevent white space.I remove the height of the scroll div.  And most important you need to change the hover state #scroll to anchor tag(You can make any class or use css selector for this). Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/u1zdn80p/5/) check the modified CSS part.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 50%;
}

#scroll a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table-cell;/* this prevents vertical whitespace */
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#scroll a .hover {
  height: 100%;
  
}

 a:hover{
  opacity: .3;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

a:hover .text {
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0; z-index:4;
  margin-top: 41px;
 margin-bottom: 41px;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
  

<a href="http://www.google.ca"><img src="http://www.fotoviva.co.uk/image/cache/data/prods/doug-blue-lake-500x500.jpg" class="hover" />
    <p class="text">Lake</p>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.ca"><img src="http://wannasmile.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/c76c_Gordon-McBryde-Field-Sunset-500x500.jpg" class="hover" />
    <p class="text">Sunset</p>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.ca"><img src="http://creativefan.com/important/cf/2012/10/patio-garden-ideas/nice-patio-gardeen.jpg" class="hover" />
    <p class="text">Garden</p>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.ca"><img src="http://globotours.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Desert-Safari-Dubai-500x500.jpg" class="hover" />
    <p class="text">Desert</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This was great, thank you! The only thing not working is setting the image opacity which I am working to figure out now. Again, thank you!

Comment: Yes, that is what I did to fix it. Thank you. One question with that, now when I hover the image, it fades and text appears, but if my mouse is hovering over the text, the image will not fade. Is there a quick fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

First off, please close your anchor tags `<a href='foo'>bar</a>`

Next, separate your images into separate divs and assign each a class='scroll' instead one big div with id='scroll'

see this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g061febd/1/)

Comment: But then the images are not in a horizontal scroll like I need them to be.. But I will be sure to close tags.